# Can you recognise this debugging system? How can I switch it off?

Tags: plugin-system, debugging

New to vim, and learning python. After I run code I get debugging comments like you can see in this screenshot on the left (S> and >>):

[image]

When I move to a line marked S> I can see below in my status bar a comment about an error or a suggestion regarding the line.

Mentioning I'm using kite. Perhaps it's a kite feature? Or maybe something native to vim? I would like to know how to manually control it. Thanks!

Comment: You're question is a little unclear. Can you explain your workflow? It *sounds* like you're running the code, and then you get "comments"—are you talking about `# Printing in colors...` or the signs (`S>`, `>>`) on the left? Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: The signs could be from ALE or Syntastic or similar; possibly from Kite.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - I edited my question, thanks for having noticed. I was referring to the S> and >> signs.

Comment: The feature is called signs; again, hard to tell what plugin is causing it, but probably a linter as i mentioned

Comment: See the section "Check the plugins" of [how do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: `:set signcolumn=no`

Answer (score 1):

As [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) replied:

```
:set signcolumn=no
```

seems to solve the issue. Thanks!